# iOS Check If IndexPath is beyond bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, nsindexpath

I wondered if anyone can shed any light, I have a list of selected players. Basically if a user taps on a indexRow that does not exist yet, I want to create it on tap.

I am currently doing this to check;

```
if ([self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] == nil) {
```

It's just crashing with this;

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'
*** First throw call stack:
```

The exact method below;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (indexPath.section == 2 && tableView == self.tableView) {

        if (!self.usersSelectionArray || !self.usersSelectionArray.count || indexPath.row < [self.usersSelectionArray count]) {

            // Create blank array and push to players

            // Push to Players Screen
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
            ListOfPlayersViewController *efvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ListPlayers"];
            [self.navigationController presentViewController:efvc animated:YES completion:nil];

        } else {

        if ([self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] == nil) {

            // Push to Players Screen
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
            ListOfPlayersViewController *efvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ListPlayers"];
            [self.navigationController presentViewController:efvc animated:YES completion:nil];

        } else {

            NSDictionary *cellDict = [self.usersSelectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            // Save Names
            [prefs setObject:[cellDict objectForKey:@"first_name"] forKey:@"teamFirstName"];
            [prefs setObject:[cellDict objectForKey:@"last_name"] forKey:@"teamLastName"];
            [prefs setObject:[cellDict objectForKey:@"avatar"] forKey:@"teamAvatar"];

            // Push to Info Screen
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
            PlayerInfoViewController *info = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayerInfo"];
            [self.navigationController presentViewController:info animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        }
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 2 && tableView == self.awayTeamTableview) {

        NSDictionary *cellDict = [self.awaySelectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Save Names
        [prefs setObject:[cellDict objectForKey:@"first_name"] forKey:@"awayFirstName"];
        [prefs setObject:[cellDict objectForKey:@"last_name"] forKey:@"awayLastName"];

        // Push to Players Screen
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
        ManualPlayerViewController *manual = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ManualPlayer"];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:manual animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    int rowNumber = indexPath.row;
    [prefs setInteger:rowNumber forKey:@"rowNumber"];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: can you just add more code. your didselect code and cellforrowatindex code

Comment: Can you be more specific what you are trying achieve?

Comment: yeah i think we could help you if you could show more code of your datasource/delegate methods

Comment: Added method in edit - thanks

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath will not get called if user taps on indexRow that does not exist.

Comment: Where am I calling it again?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be inside the tableview datasource method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Make sure that you are pickin elements from array is with correct index

Comment: I am not sure it could be? As this method is already called. It's on press off didSelect it crashes

Answer (score 0):

In didSelect method

you can use

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if(array.count>indexPath.row)
{
// do you stuff
}
}
```

Comment: This still causes a crash on this LOC.

Comment: array.count<indexPath.row